# Add comma with space between columns in sqlite SELECT using java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have these columns (`MemberId`, `City`, `State` and `Postal`) *and* (`FirstName` and `LastName`)  in sqlite table `tblMember`.

I want to create a query in java like this:

```
SELECT (LastName FirstName) AS 'LastName FirstName', 
       (City, State Postal) AS 'City, State Postal' FROM tblMember;
```

So for I have searched and tried below code for creating above query in java as like this:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{"LastName FirstName", "City, State Postal"};
String fields = "";

for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    // replace comma Plus space
    String field = columns[i].replaceAll(", ", " || \", \" || ");
    // replace space
    field = field.replaceAll(" ", " || \" \" || "); 
    fields += ",("+field+") AS '" + columns[i] + "' ";
}
String query = "SELECT MemberId"+fields+" FROM tblMember ";
```

**Note:** In above code I've used `||` sqlite operator for columns concatenation. But, it combines the spaces successfully but not combining the comma with space and showing below syntax error:

> SEVERE: null
>   java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "||": syntax error)
>     at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
>     at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901)

Please help me in this problem!

Comment: And what does your query string look like after all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your primary issue is that the first `replaceAll` introduces spaces which are then replaced by the 2nd `replaceAll`.

I believe that the following may be what you want :-

```
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        // replace comma Plus space
        String field = columns[i].replaceAll(", ", "||',ASPACEHERE'||");
        // replace space
        field = field.replaceAll(" ", "||' '|| ");
        field = field.replaceAll("ASPACEHERE"," ");
        fields += ",("+field+") AS '" + columns[i] + "' ";
    }
    String query = "SELECT MemberId"+fields+" FROM tblMember ";
```

- Instead of double quotes `"`'s, single quotes were used `'`, as they are simpler to use.
- All spaces were removed where they were not specifically required.
- Where a space was required in the first `replaceAll` an indicator for the need of a space was used so that the space added was not replaced by the 2nd `replaceAll` (ASPACEHERE was used as the inidcator).
- A third `replaceAll` was added to replace the inidcator (**ASPACEHERE**) with a space.

This results in a query :-

```
SELECT MemberId,(LastName||' '|| FirstName) AS 'LastName FirstName' ,
    (City||', '||State||' '|| Postal) AS 'City, State Postal'  FROM tblMember
```

Instead of :-

```
SELECT MemberId,(LastName || " " || FirstName) AS 'LastName FirstName' ,
    (City || " " || || || " " || ", || " " || " || " " || || || " " || State || " " || Postal) AS 'City, State Postal'  FROM tblMember
```

The first (the corrected query) results in (using sample data as below) :-

[image]

The entire testing SQL used was (the SELECT SQL being copied from the ***query** variable being output):-

```
DROP TABLE If EXISTS tblMember;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblMember (MemberId INTEGER, City TEXT, State TEXT, POSTAL TEXT, LastName TEXT, FirstName TEXT);
INSERT INTO tblMember VALUES(1,'Oxford','Oxfordshire','OX12 0ND','Bloggs','Fred');
SELECT MemberId,(LastName||' '|| FirstName) AS 'LastName FirstName' ,(City||', '||State||' '|| Postal) AS 'City, State Postal'  FROM tblMember;
```